# My second application pool not work , ('provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred ..)

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis, .net-core, windows-server-2019

I have two websites on my Windows Server 2019 VPS,

- **WEBSITE1 is working correctly**.
- I created a 2nd application pool for WEBSITE2, with the same configuration as WEBSITE1. (**same Connection String too**)

But when I try to access WEBSITE2 I have this error below.

```
Win32Exception: Unknown error (0x89c5010a)
Unknown location

   SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. 
Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.
)
```

**Connection string WEBSITE1;**

```
"Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDb;Database=DBWEBSITE1;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=180"
```

**Connection string WEBSITE2;**

```
"Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDb;Database=DBWEBSITE2;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=180"
```

**SQL VERSION :** `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)`

**Framework :** `.NET CORE 3.1`

I don't think it's a WEBSITE2 package issue. because when I put it on the WEBSITE1 directory it works fine.

Do you have any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you [create the instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) DBWEBSITE2?

Comment: @Steve Yes i have the instance 'MSSQLLocalDB'
And when i use 
-> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn>sqlcmd -S (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

1> EXEC sp_databases;
2> GO

I have all my Databases :
DBWEBSITE1
DBWEBSITE2

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find a solution.

I **deleted and recreated** the database `DBWEBSITE2` database Manually.